# Jquery Images Banner for resposnive website

Tags: jquery, image, responsive-design, slider, slideshow

I want a jquery banner slider  like this http://www.android.com/ . The slider image not reduce height too small and it best fit in all size of device  . Could you suggest me like this type of responsive content image slider.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one here [Full Width JQuery Slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html) have a look.

I would suggest you to do some research before posting a Question. Simplest way is to search on google you will find many answers if you find one post it here as a possible answer so it can help others.

Comment: thanks for your reply...i have checked in many times..i didnt find it like this...once more the image slider that you give here is too small height in mobile view ..

Comment: If you have already checked some options before you can put them in your Question, so that when someone want to answer he knows it and then can suggest something else. What do you mean by TOO SMALL please explain. thanks.